# Create tkinter progress widget at the start of function and destroy at end of function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a somewhat long bit of code that I've tried to simplify here to ask my question. There are actually many lines after the readfile in my real code, to process that data and it can be quite lengthy depending on the size of the file read.

Func1 is triggered by pressing Bt1.

I want the steps of Func1 to execute in the following specific order

1. Bt1 to be destroyed
2. progress (my progress bar) to appear on screen
3. The file to be read.

How would I best edit this code below to do this.

I'm not worried that the progress bar doesn't mean anything specific. I'm fine it just displaying to notify something is being processed.

```
root=Tk()
root.title('text')
root.configure(background="ghost white")

def func1:
        Bt1.destroy()
        progress = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL, mode = 'indeterminate')
        readfile = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
       
      
Bt1 = Button(root, command = func1)
Bt1.grid()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the lengthy task in a thread and use `StringVar` and `wait_variable()` to notify the main thread when the task is completed.

Below is a modified code:

```py
import threading

...

def lengthy_func(var):
    readfile = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
    # other lengthy tasks
    # ...

    # task completed, notify main thread
    var.set('')

def func1():
    Bt1.destroy()
    progress = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, mode='indeterminate')
    progress.grid()
    var = StringVar()
    threading.Thread(target=lengthy_func, args=(var,), daemon=True).start()
    progress.start(10) # start the progress bar animation
    root.wait_variable(var) # wait for the lengthy task to complete
    progress.destroy()
```

Comment: This worked great. I need to go learn more about this.